# What would be an appropriate way to analyze a dataset with nominal dependent variables with reapeated measures for some but not all subjects

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, cochran-q

I am trying to find the correlation between several clinical observations/demographic characteristics and the presence of certain electroencephalographic (EEG) features. The EEG features are my dependent variables.

My problem is that some patients have repeated measures while some don't (anywhere from 8 to 1 measurements per patient). The people who want this analysis absolutely want to use all available data.

I think this means I need to use a multinomial linear regression with the clinical observations as fixed effects and patient IDs as random effects. Is that too complicated? Is there a simpler way to analyze this?

I also thought maybe I could try to turn the nominal variables into binaries, but I think that would mean I would lose information.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: How many participants have more than one measure and how many have only one? How many classes in the nominal outcome variable (and are they purely nominal, no chance of seeing them as ordinal)?

Comment: @Sointu most (14) patients have at least two measurements, only 2 have only 1. But they have different numbers of measurements (4 patients have 2, 6 have 3, 1 has 7, and so on). And the variables are definitely nominal :c.

Comment: Ah, OK, so you have 16 participants in total? I'm sorry but I don't see how you could get reliable results from any regression model with such a small sample size :( A very crude rule of thumb is to have at least 10 observations per independent variable and you mention you have several independents? I'm afraid no statistical test gives you any reliable output in that situation.

Comment: To add: in general, multilevel models would have little problem with the kind of data you describe (where a minority of subjects have 1 observation and the rest have varying numbers). Data being unbalanced is not the problem here but the small sample size.

Comment: I know, but people just give me data, they don't ask before designing the studies :(.

Comment: Do you really think there's nothing to be done? I usually work with omics data, so I know it is possible to work with high-dimensional data, at least in life sciences. I have read a lot of statisticians complain though XD. Could you explain how you would use multilevel models if there were more samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put this as an answer to get more space. And, I feel your pain of getting non-optimal data from others.

So, I'm not statistician so I'm not gonna categorically say there is nothing to be done, but personally, I wouldn't try to to run any kind of regression with 16 participants. Maybe a non-parametric correlation if you had two numeric variables, or a comparison of means if you could assume a very large effect size. But not a regression with several independents. I think data visualization without any testing is recommended in this kind of situation. However, maybe post a new question focusing on the sample size issue, I think you will get insightful answers from statisticians :)

Bayesian modelling can handle small sample sizes better than frequentist, so you may want to look into that.

Re: if the data was larger: I think a multilevel multinomial logistic regression would work fine and I think a random intercept model (with a random intercept of participant and then all your independents as fixed effects) would be a good choice. Maybe even a random slope model with random slopes for some of your independents if enough of your participants had at least 3 observations. For instance in R, the package mlogit can handle those.
Good luck and sorry I couldn't help more!

Edited for grammar

Comment: Hey i just thought of something! Do you think I could just make a separate multilevel model for each pair of dependent and independent variable? Then I could correct p values with bonferroni.

Comment: That would produce the same number of comparisons than one model for each dependent, so it doesn't really change things compared to one model per dependent.

Comment: Oh :( okay, thanks